# Populating a listbox in a userform by finding a specific word within the excel spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to create a userform that will populate by finding a field containing the word "Lisa" then using the offset function to add the contents of the cell below to my listbox.

My current code only shows the listbox but with no content:

```
Sub Lab_ClearProcess()

'look for "Lisa"
Dim rngFound As Range
With ActiveSheet.cells
    Set rngFound = .Find("Lisa", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        'something is found
        'select box in row below
        'display text in list box
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        UF_ClearForm.ListBox1.AddItem
    Else
        'nothing found, show text box saying "No Processes can be found"
        MsgBox "No Processes can be found"
    End If
End With

UF_ClearForm.Show

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you are misunderstanding how the method `AddItem` works, it doesnt just add your selection into the listbox, you have to provide the parameter: `UF_ClearForm.ListBox1.AddItem CSTR(rngFound.Offset(1, 0).Value)`

Comment: @Banana thank you! That was an easy fix!  Is it possible to add a loop to this code as it should find more than one "Lisa" within the sheet (therefore more than one item should appear in the listbox)?

Comment: You should watch these videos before preceding: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5), [Excel VBA Introduction Part 15a - Find and FindNext](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=_ZVSV9Y7TGw&index=17&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: sure its possible, with `FindNext` like Thomas suggested, there is even a method on one of the answers here on stackoverflow that returns an array of all search results, i just dont remember where i saw it.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasInzina and @ Banana, still getting a handle on the different functions but have managed to make it work with FindNext :)